# QEmu `eject` complains device is not found while it is there

Tags: qemu

I need to eject a floppy from QEmu 3.0 monitor, but the command surprisingly fails complaining the device is not found, while it is really there.

Listing of devices:

```
(qemu) info block
fda: dos-6-22/Dos622-1.img (raw)
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[11]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback

hda: hda.img (raw)
    Attached to:      /machine/peripheral-anon/device[1]
    Cache mode:       writeback
```

Eject command result:

```
(qemu) eject fda
Device 'fda' not found
```

This is so although this documentation says this is how I have to do: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Change_cdrom (just that I want to eject the floppy instead of the CD‑ROM).

The `change` command complains the same:

```
(qemu) change fda dos-6-22/Dos622-2.img raw
Device 'fda' not found
```

Is this a bug or me doing something wrong?

I tried using different node names, with always the same result.

**Update:**

I’m pretty sure there is no correct answer and it’s rather a bug, which I just submitted: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1799766.

Answer (score 1):

I’m posting as an answer, but I’m not strictly sure. I can just say, if I understand correctly, this is a bug.

The answer comes in two parts.

First part, is a stripped down failing invocation:

```
qemu-system-i386 \
   -monitor stdio \
   -machine type=isapc,vmport=off \
   -blockdev driver=file,node-name=fda-img,filename=fda.img \
   -blockdev driver=raw,node-name=fda,file=fda-img \
   -global isa-fdc.driveA=fda

(qemu) info block
ide1-cd0: [not inserted]
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[19]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

sd0: [not inserted]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

fda: fda.img (raw)
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[13]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback
(qemu) eject fda
Device 'fda' not found
```

Second part, is the same without the last argument `-global isa-fdc.driveA=fda`:

```
qemu-system-i386 \
   -monitor stdio \
   -machine type=isapc,vmport=off \
   -blockdev driver=file,node-name=fda-img,filename=fda.img \
   -blockdev driver=raw,node-name=fda,file=fda-img

(qemu) info block
ide1-cd0: [not inserted]
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[19]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

floppy0: [not inserted]
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[13]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed

sd0: [not inserted]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
(qemu) eject floppy0
```

There is more error when `-global isa-fdc.driveA=fda` is removed. However, the documentation says:

> -global driver=driver,property=property,value=value
>   Set default value of driver’s property prop to value, e.g.:
>
> qemu-system-i386 -global ide-hd.physical_block_size=4096 disk-image.img
>   In particular, you can **use this to set driver properties for devices which are created automatically by the machine model**. To create a device which is not created automatically and set properties on it, use -device.
>
> -global driver.prop=value is shorthand for -global driver=driver,property=prop,value=value. The longhand syntax works even when driver contains a dot.

What I put a stress on in the quote, suggest I’m not misusing `-global` and that’s most probably a bug.

**Update for more details:**

It seems using `-drive` instead of `-device` and `driveA` assignment, the result is not the same, although RedHat documentation recommands using `-device` instead of `-drive` and QEmu 3.0 documentation says `-drive` is essentially a shortcut for `-device` (“essentially”, not telling about the difference).

Below, two cases, with an except of `info block` and an excerpt of `info qtree`.

With this one, `eject floppy0` works:

```
qemu-system-i386 \
   -monitor stdio \
   -machine type=isapc,vmport=off \
   -drive format=raw,if=floppy,media=disk,file=fda.img \
   -device isa-vga,vgamem_mb=1 \
   -serial msmouse

[…]

floppy0 (#block156): fda.img (raw)
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[12]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback

[…]

  dev: isa-fdc, id ""
    iobase = 1008 (0x3f0)
    irq = 6 (0x6)
    dma = 2 (0x2)
    driveA = ""
    driveB = ""
    check_media_rate = true
    fdtypeA = "auto"
    fdtypeB = "auto"
    fallback = "288"
    isa irq 6
    bus: floppy-bus.0
      type floppy-bus
      dev: floppy, id ""
        unit = 0 (0x0)
        drive = "floppy0"
        logical_block_size = 512 (0x200)
        physical_block_size = 512 (0x200)
        min_io_size = 0 (0x0)
        opt_io_size = 0 (0x0)
        discard_granularity = 4294967295 (0xffffffff)
        write-cache = "auto"
        share-rw = false
        drive-type = "144"
```

With this one, `eject fda` does not work:

```
qemu-system-i386 \
   -monitor stdio \
   -machine type=isapc,vmport=off \
   -blockdev driver=file,node-name=fda-img,filename=fda.img \
   -blockdev driver=raw,node-name=fda,file=fda-img \
   -global isa-fdc.driveA=fda \
   -device isa-vga,vgamem_mb=1 \
   -serial msmouse

[…]

fda: fda.img (raw)
    Attached to:      /machine/unattached/device[12]
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback

[…]

  dev: isa-fdc, id ""
    iobase = 1008 (0x3f0)
    irq = 6 (0x6)
    dma = 2 (0x2)
    driveA = ""
    driveB = ""
    check_media_rate = true
    fdtypeA = "auto"
    fdtypeB = "auto"
    fallback = "288"
    isa irq 6
    bus: floppy-bus.0
      type floppy-bus
      dev: floppy, id ""
        unit = 0 (0x0)
        drive = "fda"
        logical_block_size = 512 (0x200)
        physical_block_size = 512 (0x200)
        min_io_size = 0 (0x0)
        opt_io_size = 0 (0x0)
        discard_granularity = 4294967295 (0xffffffff)
        write-cache = "auto"
        share-rw = false
        drive-type = "144"
```